# How to validate dynamically generated input box with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, validation

Hi, I have a form which has an ajax function which appends the data when the user enters the code and selects a value from the combo box. Since the data which is appended has dynamic rows I want to validate those input boxes so that a user can only enter a value such as 01, 02, 03....10 and if the user tries to enter a value which is greater than 10 it should display an alert box. So far, I have the script which does that but since the name attribute keeps on changing the validation doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me out please?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
  var xmlhttp = false;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e1) {
        xmlhttp = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

function getfunit2(makhcode, cmbmon) {
  var strURL = "subjsele2.php?makhcode=" + document.nigran.makhcode.value + "&cmbmon=" + document.nigran.cmbmon.value;
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
  if (req) {
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        // only if "OK"
        if (req.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById('suboth').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        } else {
          alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
        }
      }
    }
    req.open("POST", strURL, true);
    req.send(null);
  }
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$makhcode=$_GET["makhcode"];

$cmbmon=$_GET["cmbmon"];
$monno1 = "mon$cmbmon";


$con = mysql_connect('localhost', '****', '*****');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$scomp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE compulsory !='1' ORDER BY ordby")or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($scomp)>0){
 echo "<table>";
   while($csub = mysql_fetch_assoc($scomp)){
         $msubjcode = $csub["code"];

         $csubqry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nigstat WHERE makhcode='".$makhcode."' AND subcode='".$msubjcode."'") or die(mysql_error());
         $fetchmon = mysql_fetch_array($csubqry) ;
         $mmonval =  $fetchmon["$monno1"];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='200px'><font color='#FF0033'><strong>".$csub[name]."</strong></td><td><input id='s_id' name='s_$csub[code]' type='text' onkeypress=\"return chknum()\" size='1' maxlength='2' value='$mmonval'></td><input type='hidden' name='$mmonval' size='3' maxlength='3'>";
    echo "</tr>";

}


echo "</table>";
 }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <table border ="0px" width="100%">

            <tr>
                <td align="right" width="58px"><label class="" for="element_1"><font size="3px"><b>Code</b></font></label></td><td><input id="makhcode" name="makhcode" onkeyup="showyear('makhsele.php?makh='+this.value); getfunit(); getfunit2();" type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" value=""/></td><td><label class="description" align="right" for="element_1">Month</label></td><td><select id="cmbmon" name="cmbmon" class="" onchange="getfunit(); getfunit2();" style="font-size:14px;">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>

                </td>
            </tr>
   </table>
    <p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p>
    <div id="makhhint" style=""></div>
    <p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />

    <table border="0px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

      <th><div class="form_description"><h2>Compulsory Subjects</h2></div></th>      
      <th><div class="form_description"><h2>Other Subjects</h2></div></th>
      <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
    <div id="subcomp" align="left" align="top" style="background-color: #99FFFF;border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;">

    </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
  <div id="suboth" align="left" align="top" style="background-color: #FFFFCC;border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;">

    </div>
```

Comment: y do u relay on name use id instead.

Comment: i am using id but even that is not working

Comment: actually where you want to validate ? server or client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function to validate code

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="validate_code(this)">

 function validate_code(that)
 {

   if(isNaN(that.value)==true || that.value>10)
    {
        that.value='';
        alert('enter a valid value');
    }
     return true
  }
```

link to example [validation example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuhJE/2/)

Comment: does it require to pass the parameters such as getelements by Id??

Comment: which place do you want to validate ,and i suppose makhcode is the place you want to validate

Comment: i want to validate the input field which is generated in php file 
<input id='s_id' name='s_$csub[code]' type='text' onkeypress=\"return chknum()\" size='1' maxlength='2' value='$mmonval'></td><input type='hidden' name='$mmonval' size='3' maxlength='3'> this one

Comment: <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
      
             document.getElementById("s_1").onkeyup=function(){
             var input=parseInt(this.value);
             if(input<0 || input>10)
             alert("Value should be between 0 - 10");
             return;
         }    
     </script> see i am usinh this to validate the input but somehow  it is not working

Comment: so will this code be able to validate the dynamically generated textboxes??

Comment: yaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: ok there are lot of other ways of registering events and validation in js ..please study those things by googling